# Pythonic way to get `package.module.Class`

Tags: python, string, import, module

Given a string a the form `'package.module.Class'`, is there any simple way in Python to get the class object directly (assuming the module isn't yet imported)?

If not, what is the cleanest way to separate the `'package.module'` part from the `'Class'` part, `__import__()` the module, and then get the class from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
def str_to_obj(astr):
    '''
    str_to_obj('scipy.stats.stats') returns the associated module
    str_to_obj('scipy.stats.stats.chisquare') returns the associated function
    '''
    # print('processing %s'%astr)
    try:
        return globals()[astr]
    except KeyError:
        try:
            __import__(astr)
            mod=sys.modules[astr]
            return mod
        except ImportError:
            module,_,basename=astr.rpartition('.')
            if module:
                mod=str_to_obj(module)
                return getattr(mod,basename)
            else:
                raise
```

Comment: Does the underscore in `module,_,basename` have any special meaning, or is it just the name of the object?

Comment: @Paul:  `'scipy.stats.stats.chisquare'.rpartition('.')` returns a 3-tuple: `('scipy.stats.stats', '.', 'chisquare')`. The middle string is just junk. The underscore, `_`, is valid variable name, and is often used to indicate the variable is junk. Though I've seen it used for other purposes as well...

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
def import_obj(path):
    path_parts = path.split(".")
    obj = __import__(".".join(path_parts[:-1]))
    path_remainder = list(reversed(path_parts[1:]))
    while path_remainder:
        obj = getattr(obj, path_remainder.pop())
    return obj
```

This will work on anything that can be `getattr`'d from the module, e.g. module level functions, constants and so forth.